# How to update database using OleDbDataAdapter with sql query?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have this code:

```
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT col1, col2 "
                                                  + "FROM tab1", 
                                                    connection);
```

I want to be able to do like this:

```
dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand(
            "UPDATE tab1 SET col1 = col1*2, col2 = 300"
          + "WHERE col1 = 5", connection);
```

How to do this right ?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use it like this:

```
var cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE tab1 SET col1 = col1*2, col2 = 300 WHERE col1 = 5", connection);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You don't need a data adapter.

Comment: I've got this exaption: `ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.` on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: @William, Is the connection you passed in `null`?